# Why is my django code for POST Method not working?

Tags: python, django, post, get

I am working on a django website and I am trying to receive data from the user through POST Method. The error message is :

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /prediction/
'date1'
Request Method: GET
```

Why is the request Method still GET even though I have POST in my views.py?

Views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from apple.models import predictions

# Create your views here.


def home_view(request):
    
    pre = predictions.objects.filter(date='2021-01-15')
    return render(request, 'homepage.html', {'prediction': pre})

def read(request):

    final_date = str(request.POST["date1"])
    price = predictions.objects.filter(date=final_date)

    return render(request, 'results.html', {'price':price})
```

This is my 2nd HTML page **Results.html** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <title>Prediction Page</title>
</head> 

<body>
    <h1>"The Predicted price for this date is:" + 
        "{{price}}"</h1>
</body>

</html>

<style>
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

    html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        background: #331952;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: center;
        letter-spacing: 1.2px;

    }
</style>
```

This is the main HTML Page  - homepage.html ( from where 'date1' is coming from ) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <title>Apple Stock Price Predictor</title>
</head> 

<body>
    <div class="login">
        <h1>Predict Apple Stock Prices for Tomorrow</h1>
        <h3>Enter the date for tomorrow to predict the Apple Stock Price for tomorrow</h3>

        <form action="read" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <input type="text" name="date1" placeholder="Tomorrow's Date" id="form-submit" />

            <input type="button" id="button-submit" value="Predict"></input>
        </form>

        <br>
        <br>
        <h3 id = "output"></h3>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

<style>
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

    #button-submit {
        background-color: #ba0b0b;
        border: none;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 8px;
        padding: 14px 40px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #button-submit:hover {
        background-color: #770e0e;
        box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    }

    * {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
        -o-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        background: #331952;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: center;
        letter-spacing: 1.2px;

    }

    .login {
        position: absolute;
        top: 40%;
        left: 50%;
        margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;
        width: 450px;
        height: 400px;
    }

    .login h1 {
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    input {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        background: rgba(134, 56, 56, 0.3);
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 13px;
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 45px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.2), 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
        -webkit-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
        -moz-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
        -o-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
        -ms-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
        transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
    }

    input:focus {
        box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 45px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Can you add the `html` file also by editing question? Also `MultiValueDictKeyError` means you have no data in `POST` with that `data1` key.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to put the view method in a class view ?

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View

class LoginView(View):
    def post(self, request):

        final_date = str(request.POST["date1"])
        price = predictions.objects.filter(date=final_date)

        return render(request, 'results.html', {'price':price})
```

and use in urlpatterns

```py
from .views  import LoginView

urlpatterns += [
    path("/prediction/", LoginView.as_view())
]
```

Comment: When I go to the url for the specific site : http://127.0.0.1:8000/prediction/, This doesn't work, This gives me an HTTP error: This page isn’t working.